# Using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-integration, semigroup-of-operators

In a demonstration of a theorem I have...$A:X\to X $ a bounded operator, $X $ a banach space and
$$e^{tA}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r} e^{\lambda t } R (\lambda ; A) \ d\lambda$$

With uniform norm, where $R (A, \lambda)=(\lambda I - A)^{-1} $, $\mu >r>\|A\| $ and $C_r $ is the complex circunference with center in the origin. The author so write... since outside $C_r $ the integrand is analytic and $$\|R (\lambda ; A)\|\leq C|\lambda |^{-1} $$ we can chift the patch of integration from $C_r$ from the line $Re \lambda =\mu $ by cauchy's theorem. I dont understed how did he use the cauchy theorem. Every hint I am thanks. I need show that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r} e^{\lambda t } R (\lambda ; A) \ d\lambda=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mu - i \infty }^{\mu + i\infty }e^{\lambda t } R (\lambda ; A) \ d\lambda$$

Comment: I would maybe help if you add some details. In particular, you should maybe define the involved objects. What kind of operator is $A$ for example? And what is $B$ supposed to be? In which kind of space are you working? Your question, as currently stated, is not well posed!

Comment: Yes A=B is a bounded operador and $R (A;\lambda)=(\lambda I - A)^{-1} $ sorry sorry

Comment: $A:X \to X $ is a operator On banach space ... the integral is on uniforme norm

Comment: Do you know how change the path of integration over an analytic function? Here you deform the circle to a "box" with vertical lines at $\mu + i \lambda$ and $-n+i\lambda$ and horizontal lines somewhere high above and below connecting these two. The "left" vertical line is suppressed by the factor $e^{\lambda t}$ (assuming $t>0$) and will die when you move it further left, the two horizontal lines get a factor of $1$ divided by their height since the integrand is $≤\frac1\lambda$, hence you can move them away to kill these contributions also.

Comment: Ok but Where i use the cauchy theorem?

Comment: Cauchys theorem is what allows you to deform the path over domains of analyticity.